# Spring JPA Repository closest Date

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity (id, created_date). I want to create a method in my JPARepository that returns the closest row from now. CreatedDate is a ZonedDateTime. I created next methods (the parameter is ZonedTimeDate.now()):

*findTopByCreatedDateBefore* (returns first created row)

*findFirstByCreatedDateBefore* (returns first created row (why the same?))

*findTopByCreatedDateBeforeOrderByCreatedDateDesc* (returns last created row)

*findFirstByCreatedDateBeforeOrderByCreatedDateDesc* (returns last created row (why the same?))

The last two return what I want but is it the best way to use them? Why are the first two return the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just pass `PageRequest` as the argument of `findAll`, where page is 1, pageSize is 1, and order is `DESC` "createdDate"

Answer (score 0):

Because the keywords `Top` and `First` are both limiting the results to the optional number following it defaulting to 1. So they *only* define the number of elements to return, not an implicit ordering — mostly because of the fact that no ordering exists, unless you explicitly specify it.

What `top` and `first` can't be defined without any ordering semantics as most stores don't guarantee any kind of ordering of the result unless you specify sorting options. Thus, the order of the elements might even vary for each method invocation.

So in the examples you gave, the first two methods restrict the result to exactly one argument.

Comment: So how to build an expression that will return row with the closest ZonedTimeDate from now?